# Translate SQL to LINQ and how display new results into the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, razor

I have to questions:

1) How to translate this select to LINQ?

```
Select i.ID, i.Impression, 
(Select COUNT(ImpressionsId) 
    from DiaryImpressions 
    where DiaryPostsId = '2' AND ImpressionsId = i.ID) as Num from Impressions i
```

2) I have to run this query inside a loop where I could replace the hard coded value `2` for the real post ID. But how could I do this in C# with MVC3? Could someone give me any example on how it works inside foreach loop and how could I display this value in the view?

Thanx a lot =)

Comment: Is this LINQ-to-SQL, or are you using LINQ to join your objects retrieved via a datareader?

Answer (score 1):

Have you already got a database context/repository set up to communicate with the database in your MVC project? Below I'm assuming you've got a database context named dbContext.

**Note: If you're not using Razor, replace the "@" with "<%" and close with "%>"**

You can either put the item in the ViewBag, or in the Model (I prefer Model) like below. I'm not sure what you want to do with these counts, so i've put them in a list. You'll need a class to put your impression info in, i've added it below;

**Model Code:**

```
    public class MyModel
    {
        public class ImpressionInfo //just used to store your results sub class of the model
        {
            public ImpressionInfo(id, impression, diaryImpressionCount)
            {
                Id = id;
                Impression = impression;
                DiaryImpressionCount = diaryImpressionCount
            }

            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int Impression { get; set; } //is this an int? you didn't say
            public int DiaryImpressionCount { get; set; }
        }

        public MyModel()
        {
            var impressionInfo = new List<ImpressionInfo>()

            foreach (var di in dbContext.DiaryImpressions)
            {
                ImpressionInfos.Add(new ImpressionInfo(
                    di.Id,
                    di.Impression,
                    dbContext.DiaryPosts
                        .Count(dp => dp.ImpressionsId == di.ID));
            }
        }

        public List<ImpressionInfo> ImpressionInfos { get; set; }
```

then in the view

**View Code:**

```
    @model MyModel

    @if(Model.ImpressionInfos.Count > 0)
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Impression</td>
                <td>Count</td>
            </tr>
        foreach (var i in Model.ImpressionInfos)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@i.Impression</td>
                <td>@i.DiaryImpressionCount</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <p>No Impression infos</p>
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where is the LINQ conversion? =)

Comment: In the constructor for MyModel? That achieves what his SQL did? He just needs to set up his Database Context to whatever it is (Linq-To-Sql, Entity Framework, NHibernate or whatever)